# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to know what's mean the following error in OpenLayers

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I get this error only when I try to execute on the following example

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html

Comment: Don't forget about the JS bundling aspect described in the OL [Getting Started](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html) doc. See this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/342829/84870) too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get basic setup like nodejs in order to run openlayers examples.